# DOM like data structure in ANSI C

Tags: c, data-structures

What would be a good data structure to use to represent a DOM like hierarchy in ANSI C?

Comment: A [tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)).

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on your problem. What do you need? Tree structure with leaves of indeterminate type?

Comment: Using an object oriented language would be more helpful than any data structure you can make up in a non-OO one. Other than that, since DOM is a tree, I'd go with one struct per type of node, chained up in a treelike logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the most general definition of a tree:

```
struct HtmlElement
{
    ... /* Tag name, attributes, etc */
    struct HtmlElement *pFirstChild;
    struct HtmlElement *pNextSibling;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

A tree for sure...DOM is a tree structure.